# Xlabs : ImageButton doesn't show image on windows 8.1 platform (not WP)

Tags: android, windows-store-apps, xamarin.forms, imagebutton, xlabs

I'm using xlabs' **ImageButton** in a **xamarin.forms** tablet app (using VS2013). I want to run this app on Windows 8.1, android and iOS. The problem is that ImageButton control doesn't show image/icon on windows platform. It's working fine on other platforms. Please help me to get out of it.

[Image showing the buttons on 2 diff. platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MH25.png)

Comment: This is more of s bug report rather than a question.